# A Label in View with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I have a View, i would like to put a test ( a UILabel) witch when clicking it, it open me a web View with an URL ( WWW.mySite.com).
How i can do this please ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Use a button, put the text into the button, hook up the actions from the button pressedUpInside to a function which will call the UIWebView's - (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request with your URL.

Comment: Is question how to create a UIWebView? If so, two options, through Interface Builder or programmatically. Try IB. Open your XIB, bring up IB, find the UIWebView in library, drag to your window, hook it up to your IBOutlet in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Apple documentation on UIWebView and use a UIButton connected to an IBAction.  Always turn to the documentation when these kinds of questions come up.  It is really through and usually pretty well done.